# Criteria for choosing a gnls model

Tags: r

I have a problem with selecting a model, because I shall use gnls and not even our statistics guy can help me here anymore. I have 4 of them, one standard model and one using `params` to specify parameter models for the parameters in the mean function. Of both models a version with the argument `weights` to specify a variance function for modelling heteroscedasticity exists.
 I set up a model to describe my data

```
asym <- deriv(~a*exp(-b*x),
               c("a", "b"), function(x, a, b){})

fit0 <- gnls(z.tendenz ~ asym(nutrients, a, b),
              data = df,
              start =  c(a = 0.2, b = 0.3))
```

Both coefficients are significant and its AIC is -87.16. I read instead on R² you can use the estimated standard deviation of the errors for nonlinear models, which is 0.097. To model the homoscedasticity I used the formula:

```
fit0a <- update(fit0, weights = varPower(form = ~ nutrients))
```

The resulting model has also significant coefficients, its standard deviation of the errors is  0.147 and its AIC is -88.12. The `anova` said they are not significantly different from each other (p= 0.0858).

Now I have the extended model, using

```
fit3 <- gnls(z.tendenz ~ asym(nutrients, a, b),
                params = list(a ~   growth, 
                              b  ~ competitors),
                start =  c(1,0,0,0),
                data = df)
```

Its AIC is -87.96 and a standard deviation of the errors of 0.095. Of the 4 coefficients only a.(Intercept) is significant, the rest between 0.1 and 0.7. 
The last model is the updated version of model 3.

```
fit3a <- update(fit3, weights = varPower(form = ~ nutrients))
```

This has an AIC of -89.22 and a standard deviation of the errors of 0.144, but as before only a.(Intercept) is significant, the p-value of b.(Intercept) is even 0.999.

What are my criteria to choose a gnls model? By AIC I would go for fit3a, by significance of the coefficients for fit0 or 0a and by standard deviation of the errors for fit3.  Is there something like a ranking of decision criteria for gnls and how important are the p-values of the coefficients? Am I missing something completely here? I add a [image: Plot] of the fits in case that offers any help.

Thank you very much ahead!

Comment: Wrong site. You should delete this question here and post it at stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Btw., this appears to be some terrible data. It doesn't seem to really justify a decision for any of these models. For example, the rightmost point seems quite influential. Have you tried cross-validation? Also, could you maybe indicate growth and competitors in the plot (e.g., by using different shapes and color for the points)? Or even better, provide the data?

Comment: Anyway, model selection should never depend on the p-values of coefficients. Using standard deviation of residuals alone will always favor the more complex models. That's why AIC includes a penalty term for the number of parameters.